# Howto remove LUKS encrypted disk from LVM

Tags: lvm, luks

I did an install of (K)Ubuntu 18.04 with LVM and encryption.
Then I added 3 other encrypted disks to the LVM (group : kubuntu-vg).
The sequence I followed for that was for each disk :

```
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/sdc1
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 sdc1_crypt
pvcreate /dev/mapper/sdc1_crypt
vgextend kubuntu-vg /dev/mapper/sdc1_crypt
lvm lvextent -l +100%FREE /dev/kubuntu-vg/root
resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root
```

Then I updated /etc/crypttab and update-initramfs.

All of that works excellent.

I am however now concerned how I have to remove a disk if the need ever would arise. And I do not get my head around that ... What I am struggling with is that all the physical disks *seem* to show full, based on the `pvdisplay` info (all Free PE 0). While in fact I have plenty of room left.

I am newbie in LVM and I suspect it has to see with the combination of LUKS and LVM.

Can someone explain me - or point me to an accurate explanation - of how to remove a disk in the setup as I have ? I did find of course plenty of explanations for a setup without LUKS.

Comment: Is that free space used by lvm? Yes it can be done but space matters unless you just want to destroy the existing data and remove the device in question! Even at that it will affect your setup as the data lost will be fatal!

Comment: Not sure to understand the remark. What I wanted to indicate is that of the 3T only 1.5T is in use so there must be a way getting a 500G disk offloaded and removed/replaced ?